# query for a scenario using other then Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `T1`, the columns are `custid`, `customername`, `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, `deptid`. and `custid`  values are 1,2,3...so on.

But `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4` values are either 'Y' or 'N' or `NUll`.

Total table T1 is:

```
custid  Custname  Q1    Q2    Q3   Q4   deptid
1       john        y   null null null   2  
2       sammy      N    N    Y     Y     1 
3       sameer     N    N    Y     N     2 
....
```

Now when question 1 i.e field `q1` =y then `q2`, `q3`, `q4` will not asked they will be `null`, and the customer will go to `deptid` = 2.

- i.e if `q1` = y                                        then `deptid` = 2.
- if     `Q1` = n and `q2` = y                           then `deptid` = 2.
- if     `q1` = n and `q2` = n and `q3` = y and `q4` = n then `deptid` = 2.
- if     `q1` = n and `q2` = n and `q3` = y and `q4` = y then `deptid` = 1.
- if     `q1` = n and `q2` = n and `q3` = n          then  a message should be display that '' customer is not assigned to any department ''.

Note: if q1=n and q2=n and q3=n then printing the message is not so necessary

Now I want to check for this along with the if the given values in table is exact and matching with the

`deptid`

I have used the below code:

```
 select P.custid from (select custid,q1,q2,q3,q4, 
case
 when q1='Y' then 2  
 when q1='N' and q2='Y' then 2 
 when q1='N' and q2='N' and q3='Y' and q4='N' then 2 
 when q1='N' and q2='N' and q3='Y' and q4='Y' then 1 
when q1='N' and q2='N' and q3='N' then 0 
  end as deptid,DeptAssigned 
 from t1 ) P where P.deptid<>P.deptAssinged
```

Please help  me with different query's and let me know if any changes in the above code

Comment: What's the issue with your current query?

Comment: Hi Rahul, there is no issue with the current Query. but i just want  to know is there any other way(other then case statement) to find out the same scenario... as i mentioned on top... as you know in SQL, for a single scenario we can use different types of logics in different ways to find it out...i just want to know the different types of logic for the same...

Comment: To get the correct answer in your query you need to change the 'AND' with 'OR' in case case statement